# Distributions for starters

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions

I'm interested in diving head on into the linux universe, the question being: Is there a specific distributions or list of distributions better to start off or is there no difference in difficulty degree between them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been a fan of "whatever your friends use" for a long time. They'll be able to help you best with a system they use as well.

Sure there are differences between a Ubuntu and a LFS or a completely self compiled gentoo. But if you ask if Fedora or Ubuntu or... is better you'll mostly get opinions. I prefer Debian based ones like Ubuntu, but again somebody from the Red Hat world would probably prefer Fedora.

Comment: My friends don't use any linux system so I Guess I'll investigate a bit beforehand. Thanks you btw :)